# tikzpicture imported from geogebra has too much space around graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to reduce the dimension of the document (I talk about the edge).

the code is:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
%\usepackage{tikz}
%\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usepackage{pgf,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
%\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,1.0}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49019607843137253,0.49019607843137253,1.0}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]
\clip(-4.3,-5.419999999999998) rectangle (18.7,6.3);
\draw [->,line width=1.2pt] (0.0,0.0) -- (0.0,5.0);
\draw [->,line width=1.2pt] (0.0,0.0) -- (5.0,0.0);
\draw [line width=2.0pt] (0.0,0.0)-- (4.0,2.0);
\begin{scriptsize}
\draw [fill=black] (0.0,2.0) circle (2.5pt);
\draw[color=black] (-1.0,4.5) node {\huge $y$};
\draw[color=black] (4.5,-0.5) node {\huge $x$};
\end{scriptsize}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My idea of the border of the file is in the picture.

[image]

Comment: As in, removing the option `[border=2pt]`?

Comment: I try to change the dimension in 0.2pt but the dimension of the edges are the same.

Comment: And removing it altogether? There must be something that is not being drawed but that still exists making the image larger.  Also , why do you specify `0.0` in the coordinates?

Comment: because I have exported the graphics from geogebra.

Comment: @ryuk Geogebra has the strange habit of adding a `\clip (xa,ya) rectangle (xb,yb);` instruction that's usually as wrong as it can be. Also the pseudoenvironment `scriptsize` has no role whatsoever.

Answer (score 4):

Remove this line:

```
\clip(-4.3,-5.419999999999998) rectangle (18.7,6.3);
```

Answer (score 2):

I was almost asking why did you clip, and suggesting you put a temporary grid (help lines) in your drawing, then I read you imported the drawing... so the clip command was placed there by your other software mimicking some sort of "sheet" I guess, and it effectively extended, rather than clipping your drawing... try with this:

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\begin{document}
\definecolor{qqqqff}{rgb}{0.0,0.0,1.0}
\definecolor{xdxdff}{rgb}{0.49,0.49,1.0}
  \begin{tikzpicture}[
     line cap=round,
     line join=round,
     >=triangle 45,
     x=1.0cm,y=1.0cm]

    \draw [->,line width=1.2pt] (0.0,0.0) -- (0.0,5.0);
    \draw [->,line width=1.2pt] (0.0,0.0) -- (5.0,0.0);
    \draw [line width=2.0pt] (0.0,0.0)-- (4.0,2.0);
    \begin{scriptsize}
      \draw [fill=black] (0.0,2.0) circle (2.5pt);
      \draw[color=black] (-1.0,4.5) node {\huge $y$};
      \draw[color=black] (4.5,-0.5) node {\huge $x$};
    \end{scriptsize}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: very interesting! ;)